# How to send a colored text message?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-telegram-bot

I am trying to send a colored text message to a user as reply, using `sendMessage` with HTML parsing.

```
bot.sendMessage(update.message.chat_id, "<span style=\"color:blue\">foo</span>", telegram.ParseMode.HTML)
```

Sending `<span style="color:blue">foo</span>` doesn't work, as `span` is not supported:

> Bad Request: Can't parse message text: Unsupported start tag "span" at byte offset 0 (400)

I am using the `python-telegram-bot` v. 4.0.3.

Is there another way?

Comment: Which module are you using, please provide a code example

Comment: @EdoPut there you go, added both ;)

Comment: Telegram lacks this feature, so you cannot send coloured text. I have asked to add bb-code support in @BotSupport.

Comment: possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49706034/using-html-in-telegram-bot

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no documentation about the tag accepted by the bot, except the [unit test for parsemode](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/tests/test_parsemode.py).

The tags that work are `b`, `i`, `a` for bold, italic and link elements, this is what is offered, maybe there's more but I couldn't find it in the [docs](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Is there maybe some other solution other than HTML?

Comment: No, the telegram api docs describes the [messageEntity](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#messageentity) as

> mention (@username), hashtag, bot_command, url, email, bold (bold > text), italic (italic text), code (monowidth string), pre (monowidth block), > text_link (for clickable text URLs)

So there is no way to add colour to text message but you can always process the text into an image and display that.

Comment: yes, it is sad....but the few html tags supported are: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#html-style

Answer (score 3):

Your can enlight piece of text with grave character "`"

> AAAA ` `enlight piece` ` BBB

Answer (score 1):

According to the [core API docs](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#html-style), Telegram only supports the `<span>` tag for spoiler text. I tried to send a message with HTML parsing and the text:

```
"<span style=\"color:#fc5252;\">text</span>"
```

And got:

> Can't parse entities: tag "span" must have class "tg-spoiler" at byte offset 0

I'm guessing this means the `<span>` tag can only be used for spoiler text.