# Using HTML in Telegram bot

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

This is not a duplicated question.
I want to use html codes in my telegram bot that is written by c#. I searched in SO but I did not find any answer. How to do that?
I used TelegramBotSharp.
Here is my code related to the part that I explained:

```
MessageTarget target = (MessageTarget)update.Chat ?? update.From;     
if(Text.StartsWith("Hello")) {
    bot.SendMessage(target, "Hello <a href='http://google.com'> dear</a>", true);
}
```

Comment: detailed blog : http://sforsuresh.in/telegram-bot-message-formatting

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Use the following syntax in your message:

*bold text*

_italic text_

[inline URL](http://www.example.com/)

[inline mention of a user](tg://user?id=123456789)

pre-formatted fixed-width code block
```

Note:
Only the tags mentioned above are currently supported.

Tags must not be nested.

All <, > and & symbols that are not a part of a tag or an HTML entity must be replaced with the corresponding HTML entities `(< with &lt;, > with &gt; and & with &amp;).`

All numerical HTML entities are supported.

The API currently supports only the following named HTML entities: `&lt;, &gt;, &amp; and &quot;.`

Answer (score 7):

[HTML mode](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#html-style)

Pass `HTML` in the `parse_mode` field when using `sendMessage`.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to format using html you need to set "parse_mode" as "html";

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot1328912345:BBCCDDExVAKD2GOEA1mXWfXfhQ_z8Y6rRh8/sendmessage?chat_id=12345678&amp;text=Sample message&amp;parse_mode=html)
```

As of now only following tags are supported by Bot:

```
<b>bold</b>, <strong>bold</strong>
<i>italic</i>, <em>italic</em>
<u>underline</u>, <ins>underline</ins>
<s>strikethrough</s>, <strike>strikethrough</strike>, <del>strikethrough</del>
<b>bold <i>italic bold <s>italic bold strikethrough</s> <u>underline italic bold</u></i> bold</b>
<a href="http://www.example.com/">inline URL</a>
<a href="tg://user?id=123456789">inline mention of a user</a>
<code>inline fixed-width code</code>
<pre>pre-formatted fixed-width code block</pre>
<pre><code class="language-python">pre-formatted fixed-width code block written in the Python programming language</code></pre>
```

Source: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#formatting-options