# how to send html text to telegram channel?

Tags: php, telegram

hi everybody i have searched all the web but didn't find any solution for my question.
i have a small script that parse a json file in php and make a operation on it and as a result make a filtered array and send it to a telegram channel.
everything is ok but in telegram channel text is in bad format . \n and br tags not supported and show as a text in my channel.i want line break in every data in telegram .
what should i do to make a good look text in every message in telegram?
i want to have a text in telegram like this:
example :
line 1: hello world 1.
line 2: hello world 2.
line 3: hello world 3.

but in channel :
hello world 1.hello world 2.hello world 3.
    function print_data_in_telegram($code,$flag){

```
$temp = filter_data_from_json($code);
$data = "";
for($i = 0 ; $i< count($temp) ; $i++){
    if($flag ==1 ){

        $data .= $temp[$i]['Symbol'] . '{left days:' . $temp[$i]['Date'] .'}'. '\n';

    }else{

        $data .= $temp[$i]['Symbol'] . 
        '{remain days :'.(60-$temp[$i]['Date'] ).'}\n';
    }
}
return $data;
```

}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using HTML in Telegram bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49706034/using-html-in-telegram-bot)

Comment: no this is not my question.

Comment: It doesn’t look like they offer any dedicated “line break” element, you might need to use `<code>` or `<pre>` elements for this.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49706034/using-html-in-telegram-bot

Answer (score 0):

Please use html encoding text
Like `&lt;h1&gt;Hello&lt;/h1&gt;`
Follow the link for more html encoding 
https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_entities_4.asp
Hope this will help you :)

Comment: i have seen but there is no break line Entity !!

Comment: finaly i have solve my problem and write for someone like me uset code : "<pre>\n</pre>"  for line break